# bundle update foundation-rails 6.2.0.1 (was 5.5.3.2), import error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation

Hi I have a problem with update a foundation-rails 6.2.0.1 (was 5.5.3.2). I have got a import error

```
 @import 'foundation/functions';
```

when I remove this import from foundation_and_overrides.scss it works, but a stylesheets does not load. I added this imports, but not working.

```
 @import 'motion-ui/motion-ui';
 @include motion-ui-transitions;
 @include motion-ui-animations;
```

any idea please?

Comment: please show the error message here. It will be helpful for us to understand.

Comment: http://www.jpeg.cz/obrazek/eTCI

Comment: this is an error message

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your framework where to find Foundation files. For example, compass config.rb file contains line "add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss""

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
@import 'foundation/functions';
```

by

```
@import 'foundation';
```